# Javascript to auto click on hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

How do I javascript automatically click on a hyperlink (id is link_page) after 5 minutes?

Comment: You can use window.setTimeout to run code for the 5 minute feature; you can use JQuery to perform the click, don't know how you can do with JavaScript only for the click part...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to trigger the onclick event handler of that link, it could work like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('link_page').onclick();
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
    </script>
</head>
...
<body>
    <a id="link_page" onclick="alert('test')">Test</a>
</body>
```

If you want to change to the location of the link after 5 minutes, you could try:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        var linkUrl = document.getElementById('link_page').href;
        location.href = linkUrl;
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
    </script>
</head>
...
<body>
    <a id="link_page" href="http://www.google.de/">Test</a>
</body>
```

The key function in both methods is the `setTimeout()` function, which takes a callback function and a timespan in milliseconds after which the callback function is executed. More on `setTimeout()`: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Mind: I tested these on OSX / Firefox, so test these on PC, too.

Comment: don't call onclick, that won't call listeners added with addEventListener, just call click(), which simulates a user click

Answer (score 4):

doing a click in js is pretty easy:

```
function clickTheLink() {
    var a = document.getElementById('link_page');
    a.click();
}
```

you can register a startup script from server code in c#:

```
string script = "setTimeout(clickTheLink, 5*60*1000);";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "5min", script, true);
```

this appends a `script` block to the end of your html. `setTimeout` executes the function provided after the delay specified. delay is in ms, so 5 mins times 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

window.onload = function () 
{
  setTimeout('document.getElementById("link_page").click()', 1000*60*5);
};

?

Comment: ew. eval is evil, man. haven't use heard? `setTimeout(String)` will eval() the String.